# Trying to copy file from one location to another

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I'm trying to copy a file to another directory with [Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)' fileUtils. I tried this

```
FileUtils.copyFile(getOutputFile(), new File("RESULT/final_result.txt");
```

The new `final_result.txt` file contains only the first line of my output file, what did I do wrong?

Is there an alternative to [Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), or some other way I'll take any as long as it does the trick.

Comment: An alternative would be guava http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

and especially the class Files http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write the file (which you get by getOutputFile()) before this operation, be sure to flush() all changes.

Otherwise it seems to be a bug. But it is unlikely.

Comment: I flushed the filewritter which is writting into output file if you mean that, what else could I flush?

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems you forgot to close the parenthesis containing the method's arguments.

Second, are you sure getOutputFile() yields a complete file?

Comment: I'm sure that name is right and that null pointer is not thrown and that the file is there with many lines, how can I know does getOutputFile yield a complete file?

Answer (score 1):

Try `new File(Result,"final_result.txt");`
Result should be of type `File` and final_result.txt `String`

Comment: even if I put just final result .txt without result same thing happens

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to do a simple test using a debug or sleep:

1. manually delete RESULT/final_result.txt
2. run the code that creates your output file and either sleep, or use a breakpoint with debugging to stop after the files is created.
3. Manually open RESULT/final_result.txt and see what's there.
4. let your program finish it's task.

You'll either find that your write is not complete (in step 3) and you'll need to flush/close the correct ouput stream, or you'll find that the copy is doing something weird (which is less likely).